# How do I pass a JS function expression for creating an swc plugin in rust?

Tags: rust, next.js, swc-compiler

I am trying to follow this [SWC documentation](https://swc.rs/docs/plugin/ecmascript/cheatsheet#matching-boxt) for developing a plugin that can compile to wasm. The `visit_mut_callee` function has a conditional statement

```rust
if let Callee::Expr(expr) = callee {
```

`Callee::Expr(expr)` accepts a `Box<Expr>` as per documentation, being new to rust I am unsure of what exactly needs to be passed.

```rust
use swc_plugin::*;

struct MatchExample;

impl VisitMut for MatchExample {
    fn visit_mut_callee(&mut self, callee: &mut Callee) {
        callee.visit_mut_children_with(self);

        if let Callee::Expr(expr) = callee {
            // expr is `Box<Expr>`
            if let Expr::Ident(i) = &mut **expr {
                i.sym = "foo".into();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Goal**

To use the `visit_mut_callee` to detect a function expression within a codebase, the expression I would like to detect is `getMyFileMetaInfo`.

Example,

```js
<SomeReactComponent metaInfo={getMyFileMetaInfo()} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by using `Box::new` to wrap the `Expr` type with it.

```rust
let _box_expr = Box::new(build_get_file_claim_expr());
```